# openWithDefaultApplication fails on files in application folder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'll ONLY recieve an "Error #3000: Illegal path name" if I try to open a file which is placed inside the app-folder of the air. If the file is somewhere else outside of the app-folder it works.

```
private var file:File = File.documentsDirectory; 

    public function download():void{
        var pdfFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("PDF Files", "*.pdf"); 
        file.browseForOpen("Open", [pdfFilter]); 
        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected); 
    }

    private function fileSelected(e:Event):void 
    { 
        var destination:File = File.applicationDirectory
        destination = destination.resolvePath("test.pdf");
        /*
        //This works, also if the file to copy is placed inside the appfolder
        file.copyTo(destination, true);
        */

        /*This Throws me an Error #3000, but ONLY if the file is located in
        the App folder*/
        file.openWithDefaultApplication();

    }
```

When i try to get the same file and copy it to another place it's doing fine.

Why that? Something special to do if i wanna open files which are inside the appfolder?
It also don't work in debug mode - bin-debug.

Regards, Temo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading the document a few times i saw that this is not possible (it's not a bug, it's a feature!?!)

[Opening files with the default system application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS2A7C0A31-A6A9-42d2-8772-79166A98A085)

> You cannot use the openWithDefaultApplication() method with files located in the application directory.

So I do this instead:

```
file.copyTo(tempFile);
tempFile.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

Not so nice, but it works.

Comment: You are a life saver. I was bonking my head trying to figure out this cryptic error message. You'd think they'd be a little more helpful in the error messgae: "Yo, sorry, but you can't put open files in yo App Storage Directory, dawg." Or something to that effect.