# Open embedded PDF from AIR

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pdf, adobe, air

What's the recommended solution, to **open an embedded** [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) document with Acrobat (or any other reader). I've followed a similiar question [openWithDefaultApplication fails on files in application folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050898/openwithdefaultapplication-fails-on-files-in-application-folder), but this seems not to work.

```
var filename = "John_Doe-tax_return_2011.pdf"; // = my filename

var realFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(filename); 
var tempFile:File = File.createTempFile(); 

    realFile.copyTo(tempFile,true); 
    tempFile.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

I've tested it all, so it's not a directory issue

```
trace(tempFile.extension) // > tmp (?? tempFile.extension = "pdf" doesn't works)
trace(realFile.exists)    // > true (original pdf-document exists!)
```

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it as an answer instead of editing your question. If it is better than the rest of the solution proposed, you can select it as answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### solution:

**This snippet works for Windows & Apple OSX:**

```
var _myfilename = "John_Doe-tax_return_2011.pdf"; // = my filename

//run:

 //grab the original file by name (_myfilename) from your appDir:
 var realFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(_myfilename);#

 //get user's home directory:
 var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory;

 //copy the original file temponary to user's home directory:
 destination = destination.resolvePath(_myfilename);
 realFile.copyTo(destination,true);

 //open the temponary copy from user's home directory (acrobat or whatever):
 destination.openWithDefaultApplication();

//end;
```

Don't forget to delete the file again from user's home directory (regarding to your comapnie's policy).