# Opening an External SWF file using fscommand

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i'm trying to "open" an external SWF file (not load it), if a button is clicked. I want to open it like a windows user would click on it and open it, i tried to use fscommand for that:

```
import flash.system.fscommand;

openSwfFileButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openFile);
    function openFile(e:MouseEvent){
        fscommand("exec", "file.swf");
        }
```

but it doesn't work, it doesn't throw an error either, any idea why?

Comment: The result depends on the environment you are running your main SWF. It will not work from browser, for example.

Comment: i'm building a flash Air desktop app, will it work?

Comment: Then you need **NativeProcess**, not **fscommand**: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html Keep in mind, user might not have any application associated with SWF.

Comment: i tried to read the reference i found it difficult to understand how to implement it, please if you could give us an example, thank you.

Comment: The example is at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Thank a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

In Air projects, you can use below code to run targeted file in your OS default application:

```
File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("file.swf").openWithDefaultApplication();
```

about https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: Thank you, i tried this solution and it throwed "Error #3000: Illegal path name", i solved it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050898/openwithdefaultapplication-fails-on-files-in-application-folder, it finaly works, thank you.